# Openlayers, how to get correct coordinates for displaying markers on map

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I have a problem getting correct coordinates from easyui datagrid to display markers on map. As you see the latitudes are positive numbers. (They are on northern hemisphere) But the markers are somehow seen on southern. Longitudes look okay. I could not find a solution about the problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example image]

```
function showTrack() {
   var iconFeatures=[];
   var num = $('#tracker-grid').datagrid('getData').total;

   for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
        var lon=$('#tracker-grid').datagrid('getRows')[i].longitude;
        var lat=$('#tracker-grid').datagrid('getRows')[i].latitude;
        var coord = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]);
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coord)
        });
        iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
   }

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: iconFeatures //add an array of features
  });

  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({

    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      scale: 0.5,
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'img/pin-blue.png'
    }))
  });

 var vectorLayerLoc = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
  }); 

map.addLayer(vectorLayerLoc);

}
```

Comment: which projection system you are using in the `ol.View`?

Comment: Are you sure that what you pass as `lon` and `lat` are numbers? Try `var coord = ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat)]);`.

Comment: Exactly the problem was passing the coords as strings rather than floats. Problem solved. Thanks.